# HttpUrlConnection issue from Eclipse and windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10

I have written simple java code which uses HttpUrlConnection to fetch result from one website. i.e Yahoo.

My Code is as follow.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www.yahoo.com/";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        }
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();

    }
}
```

I have stop the service of Windows Firewall on my computer (windows 10)

But when I run this code from eclipse I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at com.ideas.sydney.mascotvalet.Demo.main(Demo.java:20)
```

But when I run this code from  [online editor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php) it work as expected, i.e. without exception.

Let me know if any one knows how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: Yes I am, but still I don't know how to solve this

Comment: I have tried after stop the firewall service, but issues is same, so I have set proxy and now it is working, Thanks for help